# UIButton UIButtonTypeCustom error.Unrecognized selector sent to class

Tags: objective-c, ios, checkbox, uibutton, invalid-argument

I have this error with my code. I am designing a custom `checkbox`. For that i have a `UIView` which i have customized to look like a `Checkbox`. I have another copy of my project where i used the code and it works perfectly fine. I copied the code to another mac and it wont work.It is the same code.

```
 My.m file
- (void)defaultInit
{
btn_CheckBox = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn_CheckBox.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, kImageWidth, kImageHeight);
btn_CheckBox.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
[btn_CheckBox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckBox_Deselected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn_CheckBox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckBox_Selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[btn_CheckBox addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self addSubview:btn_CheckBox];

lbl_CheckBox = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 0, self.bounds.size.width-35, 30)];
lbl_CheckBox.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
lbl_CheckBox.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont smallSystemFontSize]];
[self addSubview:lbl_CheckBox];
 }
 - (void)setID:(NSUInteger)index andSelected:(BOOL)state andTitle:(NSString *)title
{
    nID = index;
    [btn_CheckBox setSelected:state];
    lbl_CheckBox.text = title;
}

- (void)handleTap
{
btn_CheckBox.selected = !btn_CheckBox.selected;


[delegate stateChangedForID:nID withCurrentState:btn_CheckBox.selected];
}
- (BOOL)currentState
{
    return btn_CheckBox.selected;
}
```

I am getting the error at the very first line in the `method.btn_CheckBox = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];`As soon as my breakpoint hits this line it throws this error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' reason :'+[UIButton buttonWithType:]:unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3a88'.
```

My .h file

```
@protocol CheckBoxDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)stateChangedForID:(NSUInteger)index withCurrentState:(BOOL)currentState;
@end
@interface Checkbox : UIView
{
NSUInteger  nID;
UIButton    *btn_CheckBox;
UILabel     *lbl_CheckBox;

id <CheckBoxDelegate> delegate;
}
 @property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *btn_CheckBox;
```

Why am i getting this error?Any help would be great.If you need more information, please ask. Thanks...

Comment: Are you using `btn_CheckBox` somewhere else in ur class?

Comment: did you check for framework , import and target added ?

Comment: @Robin. I edited the code. That is all where the btn_Checkbox is being used in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You need `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` at the top of your .h file.

Comment: @sbwoodside.I already have the import statement in my header file

Answer (score 0):

Can you have a re-look at your error, why does it say

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' reason :'+[UIBUtton buttonWithType:]:unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3a88'.** this??

reason :'+[**UIBU**tton buttonWithType:]

it says UIBU, So I believe there is a spelling mistake at UIButton.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I typed it in here as UIBUtton..on the actual console it says UIButton buttonWithType:]..etc.its a typo here but not on the actual output.

Answer (score 0):

In the line :

```
[btn_CheckBox addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Is the method `handleTap` states as `- (void)handleTap { }` or `- (void)handleTap:(id)sender` ? If the latter one, your line should update as:

```
[btn_CheckBox addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```